# custom theme ,add media not showing images in media library

Tags: customization, themes

i am beginner with theme development, created a theme following an online tutorial. when i try to add images in a post using the add media button , it opens but shows no images , the loader just keeps spinning. But accessing the media library directly shows there are images in it.
what am i missing here ? changing the theme to any of the wordpress themes corrects the issue.But i would like to use my theme.

Comment: i disabled an options page i made for customizing the theme , like social media links etc, and everything loaded fine. now got to figure out what i did wrong in that code

Comment: i am not sure what the actual problem was, but echoing the html form instead of putting it outside the php tags worked out.